# Android emulator file reading

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I am trying one use case where I need to push a file to emulator using adb command like,
adb push "filename.txt"
This command is working and I am able to see the file in the emulator. I have pushed to /sdcard/Documents folder.
But when I am trying to read the same file using code its giving me permission error.
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

I have enabled read/write external storage permissions for the app. But still it is throwing permission exception. With the same code I am able to read a file which created using File API in app itself. But this is not able to read the file which is pushed from the adb command.

Code using to read the file is,
File(

Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
.absolutePath +"/" + "myfile1.txt"
)
file.readText()

Do we need any other permissions to read the file pushed to emulator?
Any idea?

If I push the same file to a real device, it is working, I mean app is able to read that file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which Android version are you using?

Comment: `Code using to read the file is,` That code does not read a file. It only creates a File instance.

Comment: If the emulator is running Android 10+ you need to use scoped storage API for file access outside of the app specific directories and the download folder.

Comment: I am using Android11, enabled scoped storage also.

Comment: @blackapps - YEs, this is just create file, but file.readText() is used to read content from the file

Comment: It is nonsense to say that you enabled scoped storage. You can only say that Google forces you to follow scoped storage rules and that you did. But we see that you did not.

Comment: `If I push the same file to a real device, it is working, I mean app is able to read that file.` That is just because the Android version is different there. Or the app created the file itself there.

Comment: @blackapps - App is pushed to device, not created there. and OS is same

Comment: That file under that path should be unreadable for apps on Android 11 devices as the file is not created by the app. So what special device do you owe that does behave different?

Comment: Question here is how to read the files pushed to emulator of any OS version(it may be above 10 or below 10) from our app?